# anticausal group velocity?

Tags: causality, phase-velocity

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomalous_dispersion claims:

> Recently, it has become possible to create gases in which the group 
>   velocity is not only larger than the speed of light, but even
>   negative.  In these cases, a pulse can appear to exit a medium before
>   it enters. Even in these cases, however, a signal travels at, or less
>   than, the  speed of light, as demonstrated by Stenner, et al.

Is this (''a pulse can appear to exit a medium before it enters'') a real effect, or is it due to sloppy experiments or their sloppy interpretation?

related:

[Front velocity and Superluminal group velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/240521/front-velocity-and-superluminal-group-velocity)

[In superluminal phase velocities, what is it that is traveling faster than light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6912/in-superluminal-phase-velocities-what-is-it-that-is-traveling-faster-than-light)

Answer (score 3):

The usual experimental situation where a [group velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faster-than-light#Group_velocities_above_c) greater than the speed of light occurs requires (a) an optical transmission near an absorption peak, which distorts the pulses, or (b) the presence of the [Hartman Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartman_effect), which is a quantum tunneling effect seen when the barriers are thicker.

A colleague of mine, [Herbert Winful](http://www.eecs.umich.edu/faculty/winful/), has carefully analyzed these situations in a series of papers. [Nature of “Superluminal" Barrier Tunneling](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.90.023901); also see the referenced papers.

The conclusion: faulty analysis of the situation results in unfounded claims of information transmission that is faster than the speed of light.

Some counter-analysis has been published by [Günter Nimtz et al](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%BCnter_Nimtz) in [The Superluminal Tunneling Story](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1304/1304.3155.pdf).

Comment: my question was more specifically about the anticausal claims that effects _precede_ the cause.

Comment: That's the same thing as FTL communication, hence ruled out.

Comment: Well, the paper I quoted says this itself (see the last sentence of my quote). My question is about the group velocity, which is well-known to be superluminal without violating principles of relativity.